# C++ variadic template: different priorities in gcc and nvcc/intel

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, nvcc

Having a problem with the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename... Args>
inline double foo(function<double (Args...)> fun, Args... args) {
    return fun(args...);
}

template<typename... Args, typename... ArgsTmp>
double foo(function<double (Args...)> fun, ArgsTmp... args) {
    return foo(fun, 1., args...);
}

int main() {

    function<double (double, double, double)> fun = [&](double x, double y, double z) -> double {
        return x+y+z;
    };

    cout << foo(fun) << endl;
}
```

When I compile it with gcc everything goes fine. But if I'm trying to compile it, for example, with intel or nvcc-7.5(which is actually my goal) I'm getting the following error:

```
more than one instance of overloaded function "foo" matches the argument list:
            function template "double foo(std::vector<limits, std::allocator<limits>>, std::function<double (Args...)>, Args...)"
            function template "double foo(std::vector<limits, std::allocator<limits>>, std::function<double (Args...)>, ArgsTmp...)"
            argument types are: (std::vector<limits, std::allocator<limits>>, std::function<double (double, double, double)>, double, double, double)
...
1 error
```

Is there any way to let the compiler know explicitly that when `Args==ArgsTmp` (in the second template) the following inplementation of `foo()` should be rejected?

Comment: I'm not sure how much this is going to help you, but the code is fine - the specialization of the first template should be preferred when `Args` and `ArgsTmp` are exactly the same, because the first template is more specialized than the second according to the partial ordering rules for function templates. The code works fine on GCC 5.2.0, Clang 3.7.0, and VC++ 2013 and 2015. If the error comes from the host compiler to which nvcc forwards compilation, it may be worth finding out what version that is and maybe upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try SFINAE and `enable_if`

```
template<typename... Args, typename... ArgsTmp>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::tuple<Args...>,
                               std::tuple<ArgsTmp...>>::value,
                 double>
foo(function<double (Args...)> fun, ArgsTmp... args) {
    return foo(fun, 1., args...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying for hours to figure out how to use SFINAE but ended up just thinking that I'm doing it wrong way. Though, I had to change your code a little:

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the number of arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Args>
inline double foo(std::function<double (Args...)> fun, Args... args) {
    return fun(args...);
}

// Only considered, if the number of arguments is less than the number
// of expected arguments (accepting any number of arguments may lead 
// to infinite recursion).
template<typename... Args, typename... ArgsTmp>
inline typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(ArgsTmp) < sizeof...(Args), double>::type
foo(std::function<double (Args...)> fun, ArgsTmp... args) {
    return foo(fun, 1., args...);
}

int main()
{
    // A shorter variant
    std::function<double (double)> fun = [&](double x) -> double {
        return x;
    };
    std::cout << foo(fun) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(fun, 2.0) << std::endl;
    // error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(std::function<double(double)>&, double, double)’
    // std::cout << foo(fun, 3.0, 4.0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In my case I better make sure ArgsTmp and Args are exactly the same. But that's a valid solution too.

Comment: What do you mean? It's implied that the first call of foo() goes with only one argument: a function.